# Global variable for language_id available in views and in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, global-variables

I'm trying to share a session variable in both the controllers, the views and the model.

With the following code, it is working in the controllers and in the views :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    helper_method :best_language_id

    # Returns the ID of the language to use to display the description.
    def best_language_id
        @best_language_id ||= session[:best_language_id]
        @best_language_id ||= current_project.default_language.id
        return @best_language_id
   end
end
```

But I can't call it from the model.

I would like to be able to call best_language_id either in the controllers, views and in one model, to get a fallback of the best_language_id if a translation is not found.

Example in my model (not working) :

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Retuns the attached word in the given language if exists. 
    # Otherwise, falls back on another translation
    def word(preffered_language_id)
        word = Word.find(:translation_id => self.translation_id, :language_id => preffered_language_id)
        if word.blank?
            word = translations.where(:translation_id => self.translation_id, :language_id => best_language_id)
        end
        return word
    end
end
```

I know that model should not include applicationcontroller method calls, but how is it possible to share my best_language_id accross controllers and model ?

Edit : using i18n is not the question here. Translations are not fixed string but variables in a database.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: you're wrong: you could have an ActiveRecord I18n store

Comment: I understand your comment, but as I said, i18n is not the question here because we would like to handle ourselves the vocabulary. Do you have an idea to solve my question ?

Comment: I can't understand  `def word()  ...  if word.blank?` what does that mean?

Comment: I've edited the code to show how I'm fetching a Word in the preffered_language_id, and if not existing, trying to fall back on the best_language_id.... But accessing best_language_id in this model fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your rails app, you have a base module in config/application.rb. It should be named after your application. Let's say its called MyApp. What you could do is define two methods like this:

```
module MyApp
  ...
  def self.language_id=(value)
    @language_id = value
  end

  def self.language_id
    @language_id ||= 'en' # default vaule
  end
  ...
end
```

Then, in app/controllers/application_controller.rb add a before_filter like this:

```
before_filter :language
def language
  MyApp.language_id = session[:language_id] if session[:language_id] 
end
```

Then, from all over the app, you can access the value via

```
MyApp.language_id
```

Needless to say that the approach is not thread safe so don't use it in a threaded environment.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it now. What do mean by "It should be named after your application" ? Should I create a module file lib/my_app.rb and include your code there ?

Comment: I just understand what you meant. I'd prefer to create another .rb file in lib/

Comment: Well of course you can use whatever module you like, also classes are fine.

Comment: Your solution is working very well. I used a separate module file in lib/ and it was automatically included in all models :-)

Comment: Technically, it is not included, it is just loaded so that you can use it. Including a module in a model would mean that you have its methods available there. Have a look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you switch the situation around, store the best_language_id in the model as a class accessor, then you can set and get it from your controllers and it will still be available in the models.

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :best_language_id # to store the variable
end

# Persist the content of that variable at the start of every action
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  before_filter :set_best_language

  def set_best_language
    Point.best_language_id = session[:best_language_id]
    Point.best_language_id ||= current_project.default_language.id
  end
end

# Use the variable in a controller
class SomeOtherController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @best_language = Language.find(Point.best_language_id)
    ...
  end
end

# Use the variable in a model
class SomeOtherController < ActiveRecord::Base
  def some_method
    best_language = Language.find(Point.best_language_id)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thak you. Is this solution correct if I need best_language_id  in other model than Point ? Should I then add the same accessor in all my models ? and then duplicate the Model.best_language_id = ... with all my model names ?

Comment: If you had it declared in two models at once then those are two completely separate variables that can be called and used independently of one another - you can call any model class accessor from other models, I'll update the solution with an example.